# how to handle <br> , \s like strings in json in classic asp

Tags: javascript, json, asp-classic

I am writing application in which i am creating json file for this via classic asp. json ccontains various character that may cause json error. such as /s or `<br>` . i have replaced manually this two by this code.

```
     stringin= Server.htmlencode(stringin)
    stringin= Replace(stringin, "\s" , "\\s")
```

but that `<br>` causing problem as it creates new line in json array. how to handle this? are there are more character that cause problem how to handle them ?

Comment: *"`<br>` causing problem as it creates new line in json array"* - It most certainly does not. You don't show enough code to help you, but it is extremely likely that your entire approach is wrong and cannot be fixed by changing one line of code. Show mode of your code and explain what you actually do. Three things are important: What is your input, what is your expected output, and what is that output going to be used for.

Comment: @Tomalak thanks for showing interest, problem was there was newline character are there so it was causing problem , got solution i escaped in classic asp and unescape in javascript and it works